# Lens design with few constraints

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, lenses

I'm not an expert in lens design. I need to build a lens having fixed the focal point $f$, the lens diameter $D$, the maximum thickness $d$, the refractive index $n$ and the half-angle $\theta$ entering on the lens and the angle that I want at the exiting from the lens. With these, I want to find the radius of curvature $R_1,R_2$.

In some books of optics that I used in my course of physic and I found the Lensmaker equation (because I cannot use the thin lens approximation).

$\frac{1}{f} = (n-1)\left [ \frac{1}{R_1} - \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{(n-1)d}{nR_1R_2} \right ]$

This equation don't allow me to play with the lens diameter, so looking around I found the relation between this and the numerical aperture `NA` from Fresnell equation but I'm not sure how can help me.

$n_1\sin\theta_{in} = n_2\sin\theta_{out}$

$NA = n\sin\theta = n\sin\left [ \arctan \left ( \frac{D}{2f} \right ) \right ]$

Can you help me figuring out these radius knowing all the previous variables and how take into account the whole lens diameter?

This is my geometry. The focal point is known since I have a diverging source and I want to have a planar wavefront after my lens.

[image]

Comment: Hi! You can put mathematical expressions in MathJax by wrapping them in $ symbols. To get greek letters you can just type the name preceded by a forward stroke eg \theta.

Comment: Didn't know. Thanks

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the geometry, but aren't the radii of curvature independent of the lens-diameter? So you need to pick a lens diameter consistent with the angle you want to let in, which is given by the last equation in your post, and then given the focal length you want the lens-makers equation gives you the radii of curvature. (There will be lots of solutions, I'd probably pick $R_1=-R_2$ if you're doing this by hand)

Comment: The point is that I know where is the focal length (I have a divergent source hence the focal point) and I want that the divengency angle, if we want to call it like that, my $\theta_{in}$ fixed at 45°. I want a converging lens to get  $\theta_{out}$ possibly 0°.  The lens diameter is due to mechanical constrain that need to be fulfilled and the refraction index is something that I cannot change.

Comment: I added a schema of the geometry. I need to converge, so I thought to start with a bi-convex lens and then we'll see. I guess the Lensmaker equation describes whatever shape changing the value of $R_1$ and $R_2$ (flat surface will have $R=\infty$ I suppose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focal length of a lens depends only on its thickness and radii of curvature, as appears in the lensmaker's formula you quote. Think of a single ray - as long as it enters the lens, it will be deflected according to the focal length you calculate. It simply doesn't care about the extent of your lens. A word of warning - this is true in the paraxial approximation, so if your lens is too big you no longer have a focal point. In this cases different rays will converge into different points, an effect known as spherical aberrations.

However, both the diameter and the focal length of a lens affect the amount of light it can collect from a source at its focal point, which is what the numerical aperture captures. This is of paramount importance in microscopy, where one wants to maximize the amount of light collected from a sample.

Comment: In the third formula that I wrote, the $n$ is the refraction index of the lens or outside? Or it doesn't matter?. Because as you said, I guess that one of the "constraint" that I have is not actually a constraint but something that someone tried to calculate (wrong) and this explains a few things that I'm experiencing

Comment: $n$ is the refractive index of the lens. What is the purpose of this lens if I may ask?

Comment: Is a lens for a projector with a diameter D. 
The supplier gave to me the constrains that I said but I think that actually some of them (focus, input angle ecc) are computed, not actually constrains and I believe they used the approximation for thin lenses that is fancy from a physical point of view but impossible to build since we're talking of a big lens. I guess that given the Fresnell eq (fixing the output angle) I need to compute the input angle and then find the focus length with the third formula. At the end, the radius with Lensmaker eq. Am I right?

Comment: You have the diameter and you don't need it anymore for any formula. You should just use the given focal length and invert the lensmaker formula. Note that you can simplify the equation by assuming a symmetric lens or a plano-convex lens. Those are typical types of lenses.

Comment: The problem is when I want simulate this with a tool in geometric optics (i.e. Zemax) this tool asks me the radius of curvature and also the diameter of the lens. This is why I'm feeling that I'm missing something

Comment: You should note that the lensmaker formula is true only in the paraxial approximation. Zemax doesn't use the paraxial approximation, but instead applies Snell's law to each ray to get the actual trajectory. It means that larger lenses will collect further rays which are less paraxial, and as a result those rays will converge to a different point than the calculated $f$. To summarize, the size of the lens has an effect on the optical system, and if your lens is too big the formula for $f$ is not valid anymore.

Comment: And which formula helps me in this case? I thought that this was the like the Holy Bible for lenses

Comment: Nothing helps you then. You get the situation in the second lens here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_aberration. This effect can be corrected using more complex lenses (parabolic) or by using several lenses instead of one.

Comment: That's kind of what I see in some simulations that I'm trying in some situations. In these cases I'm screwed you're saying? So the only thing that I can do is just play with the simulators to get what I want? Giving the lens diameter, the refractive index and setting the focus point, just try to play with different radius, shapes and so on? A much more "engineering" way with few computations as basis was good to have.
Just saying, since I have an input angle $\theta_{in} = 45°$ I cannot use the paraxial approximation, am I right? Because the angle is too large with respect the output I need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93782/discussion-between-eranreches-and-shika93).